# java open file and sort data

Tags: java, file, sorting

good day!who any one can help on how to sort data from my name.txt

test.text

cath
zeny
ana
dana
maria
sheila

heres my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadTextFileExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

File file = new File("name.txt");

StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();

BufferedReader reader = null;

try {

reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String text = null;




while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
contents.append(text).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

}

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

} finally {

try {

if (reader != null) {

reader.close();

}

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

}


System.out.println(contents.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Try using the code formatting tool in the future. Also, I happen to know this is a homework assignment, so you need to make an attempt to solve it yourself first. I'll give you a hint and say you need an array.

Answer (score 4):

Put the strings into a list:

```
List<string> strings = new ArrayList<string>();
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    strings.add(text);
}
```

Sort the strings:

```
Collections.sort(strings);
```

Do whatever with the sorted strings, like concatenating in a single line:

```
StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
for (string s : strings) {
    contents.append(text).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Stores cath zeny ana diana etc in a String array
String[] names=contents.split(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));

//bubble sort
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<names.length;j++)
   {
      int compare=names[i].compareTo(names[j]);
      if(compare > 0 )
         //swap names[i] and names[j]
      else
         //do nothins
   }
```

The above code should sort all the names in this array.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, don't have much time to explain ...

you could put all your strings into a linkedlist or arraylist and use the `Collections.sort( List lst )` method to sort them.

greetings